# Windows update causing system high CPU on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, updates

Over the last few days I have been having issues with my machine running very slow. The problem seemed to be with the System process consuming about 20% CPU (more specifically ntoskrnl.exe!MmProbeAndLockPages).

Many attempts to reset and/or reinstall where unsuccessful. The only options that eventually worked was to reinstall windows (fresh) with the Network cable unplugged. This prevented Windows updates during the installation.

Now, I'm quite certain it's one of the device driver updates that's causing this issue. I have Windows Updates disabled for now but I would like to turn it back on but run the updates in stages.

Is there a way to selectively approve updates one by one? I am running Windows 10 Pro on a home network (if it makes a difference).

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I think I have managed to find the problem. I've enabled Windows Update again and it went through the same process of updating drivers. Checking the list of drivers I went to the Lenovo support website (M93p in my case) and started downloading alternative drivers and install them one by one. The Intel Gfx Driver fixed the problem and now the computer is responsive again. The high CPU from the System process may have been unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such option available in Windows 10 to manually select particular update.

Keep automatic update always ON, since Microsoft keep releasing latest update.

If similar situation appears, then use SYSTEM RESTORE option.